Evaluating a combinatorial sum

Find an expression/upper bound for $$\sum_{r\le X}\frac{1}{m^r}{{k+r-1}\choose{r}}$$where $m,k$ are fixed.

Looking at the first few terms, we see that this is the same as $$\frac{1}{m}{{k}\choose{1}}+\frac{1}{m^2}{{k+1}\choose{2}}+\frac{1}{m^3}{{k+2}\choose{3}}+\cdots$$
I expect that the $1/m^a$ terms cause this sum to converge. I also wouldn't be surprised if this sum is actually known as a combinatorial result, so if anyone has a solution/reference that would be really helpful.
What I've tried so far is to brute force expand using the definition of $^nC_r$, as follows: $$\sum_{r\le X}\frac{1}{m^r}{{k+r-1}\choose{r}}=\sum_{r\le X}\frac{(k+r-1)!}{m^rr!(k-1)!},$$
but this didn't seem to be a very fruitful approach.

According to Mathematica, this series has the sum $\left(\frac{m}{m-1}\right)^k - \binom{k+x}{1+x},_2F_1(1, k+x+1, x+2, 1/m)/m^{x+1}$.

It is well known that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom nk x^n=x^k(1-x)^{-k-1}.$ Equivalently, shifting the summation index by $k$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom {n+k}k x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} \qquad (k\in \mathbb N,\,\,|x|<1).
$$
Applying this with $x\gets \frac1m$, and with $k-1$ in place of $k$, we get a closed form for the infinite version of your sum:
$$
\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac1{m^r}\binom{k+r-1}{r}
=-1+\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{r+(k-1)}{k-1}\left(\frac1m\right)^r
=-1+\frac{1}{(1-\tfrac1m)^k}
=\frac{m^k}{(m-1)^k}-1.
$$
Already, this is an upper bound for your finite sum, for all $X$. We can get a slightly simpler upper bound by applying the inequality $(1+x/k)^k\le e^x$, valid when $|x|\le k$.
$$
\frac{m^k}{(m-1)^k}=\left(1+\frac1{m-1}\right)^k\le e^{k/(m-1)}.
$$
